# asp.net button in css overlay div on masterpage not firing on click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick, master-pages, umbraco

Im fairly new to umbraco, master pages and all that, but im catching on..

I seem to have this weird problem.. I have a set of master pages with content with umbraco cms..

In the master pages i have a common menu and a login button.. This login button fires up an overlay, wich is contained in a div within the same masterpage. There is another overlay to create a new user on that same master page.. Problem is, the button OnClick in the login overlay does not fire.. Funny thing is, the required property on my textboxes does fire... You know, the message popping up saying you must enter something! But my custom validator does nothing :S

Here is the script in the header of my masterpage:

```
<script runat="server">
    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["failedLogin"] = false;
        string mail = tbLoginMail.Text.Trim();
        string pass = tbLoginPass.Text;
        tbLoginMail.Text = "TEEEEEEST!";
        PageUtil.User = PageUtil.ValidateCredentials(mail, pass);
        if (PageUtil.User == null)
        {
            Session["failedLogin"] = true;
        }
        if (Page.IsValid)
            Server.Transfer(Page.ResolveClientUrl("/"));
    }

    private void UserLoginResponse(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        if (Session["failedLogin"] != null)
        {
            if ((bool)Session["failedLogin"])
            {
                args.IsValid = false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Not even the text in the textbox gets set to teeeesst! Any1 has any suggestions?

Here is the body containing the 2 divs:

```
<body>
<a name="LoginLink" href="#overlay" class="submitbtn"><%= PageUtil.IsLoggedIn() ? "Log ud" : "Log Ind" %></a>
<form runat="server">
    <div id="overlay">
        <div id="popup">
            <!-- ANY CONTENTS -->
            <a href="">
                <img class="close_button" src="/media/Images/close.png" /></a>
            <div id="login" class="login">
                <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="login" ErrorMessage="Forkert e-mail eller password" OnServerValidate="UserLoginResponse" Display="Dynamic"></asp:CustomValidator><br />
                <label>E-mail</label>

                <asp:TextBox ID="tbLoginMail" type="text" TabIndex="1" class="input" ValidationGroup="login" placeholder="email eller brugernavn" required="true" runat="server" /><br>
                <br>

                <label>Password</label>

                <asp:TextBox ID="tbLoginPass" type="password" class="input" TabIndex="2" required="true" ValidationGroup="login" runat="server" /><br>
                <br>

                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbRememberMe" type="checkbox" TabIndex="3" runat="server" />Keep me logged in

                   <asp:Button ID="submitbtn" Text="Login" TabIndex="4" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" runat="server" ValidationGroup="login" CausesValidation="true" /><br />
                Ikke oprettet? <a href="#overlay_signup">Opret bruger!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="overlay_signup">
        <div class="overlay popup" style="height: 500px;">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="close_button" src="/media/Images/close.png" /></a>
            <div class="login">
                <label>Navn</label>

                <asp:TextBox ID="createUserName" type="text" TabIndex="1" ValidationGroup="signUp" class="input" placeholder="Navn" required="true" runat="server" /><br>
                <br>

                <label>Email</label>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp

                  <asp:TextBox ID="createUserMail" type="text" class="input" ValidationGroup="signUp" placeholder="e-mail" TabIndex="2" required="true" runat="server" /><br>
                <br>

                <label>Password</label>

                <asp:TextBox ID="tbCreateUserPass" type="password" ValidationGroup="signUp" class="input" TabIndex="2" required="true" runat="server" /><br>
                <br>

                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="submit1" class="submitbtn" ValidationGroup="signUp" Text="SignUp" TabIndex="4" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="box">
        <div id="head">
            <umbraco:Macro ID="Macro1" Alias="MenuBar" runat="server"></umbraco:Macro>
        </div>
        <div class="header">
            <umbraco:Item ID="Item2" Field="header" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <umbraco:Item ID="Item1" Field="bodyText" runat="server" />
            <div id="contentDiv">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="pageContent" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dotSeperator">...</div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p class="footerText">| Martin Stendorf Jensen | Copyright ® 2013 | <a href="mailto:mstendorf@outlook.com?Subject=Henvendelse%20fra%20website">mstendorf@outlook.com</a> | +4527126901 |</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Try to add an id to your form to see if its works.

Comment: It doesn't.. The button keeps on not responding :(

Comment: Does removing the CustomValidator allow the button click event to be triggered? It's been a while since I've worked with custom validators, but I'm pretty sure you have to set `args.IsValid` to true somewhere in there. It seems like your validation is depending on a variable set by the final event, which won't trigger because it's waiting for the validation.